# LWP::UserAgent Object Proxy Attributes in CPAN Modules

Tags: perl, perl-module

Some modules on CPAN use the LWP::UserAgent module. Some of these modules provide the ability to set attributes which are then used by the module with the UserAgent object. However, some of them do not provide such a mechanism. In such a case what is the best way of passing the attributes to the UserAgent object in the module? Specifically, I am interested in proxy attributes and the agent string.

My first thought was to refer to Chapter 10 of Mastering Perl but that seemed overkill and I'm guessing that there is a simpler solution. Is there a simpler solution?

Examples of modules that do not provide a mechanism to set proxy attributes:

[WWW::WhoCallsMe](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aWhoCallsMe)

[WWW::TV::Series](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aTV%3a%3aSeries)

Comment: The documentation for `WWW::TV::Series` says *"There also isn't support for proxy servers yet. LWP should use it from your environment if you really need it..."* so I assume you can use environment variables as described in the [`LWP::UserAgent` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-env_proxy). Judging from the documentation, neither module exposes the `LWP::UserAgent` object via a method call, so unless you want to hack the internals (which could change with the next module release), you're probably best off submitting a feature request to the maintainer.

Comment: Even loading from environment variables I would still need access to the UserAgent object, would I not? Based on what you wrote in the rest of your message I need to study Chapter 10 of Mastering Perl.

Comment: After looking through LWP::UserAgent documentation I noticed that you can set PERL_LWP_ENV_PROXY environment variable to 1 and then set the http_proxy variable to your proxy address and this will make all LWP::UserAgent objects use the proxy specified in http_proxy. The more general question of accessing attributes from a module that are not exposed via accessors or the like seems to be subclassing or patching whether that is by sending to module developer or doing it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally such modules would allow you not just to set UserAgent attributes but to entirely replace the object with one of your choice, such as a [LWPx::ParanoidAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWPx%3a%3aParanoidAgent) object (not a good choice in your case).

If you are up to the task of enhancing the offensive modules to do this, kudos to you.  If not, filing a bug report would be entirely appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not up to the task.